# Is there a generic way to check if a Laravel Model has relationships?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to write a generic function that only will fire if a Model has relationships defined but not be specific to that model.

Is there a property of a model that will tell me if that Model has any relationships regardless of what the Model is or the relationships?

Answer (score 5):

You have access to all your relations using:

```
$model->getRelations();
```

Comment: If that returns an empty array, would that mean that there are no relationships defined?

I have this function in the Model 

`$this->getRelations();`
which returns an empty array though I have relationships defined for that model.

Comment: Do you have those relations defined in database? (migrations)

Comment: How would they be defined in the migrations?

Comment: Oh no I dont have foreign keys defined in the database. I was hoping there was a predefined function that I could call that would check if the model is using "Has_Many" or something like that.

Comment: To put this in perspective, here is what I am eventually trying to do: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/cullymason/6198667)